# Call stored procedure/function with PHP in Mongo DB sharded cluster

Tags: php, mongodb, sharding

I am using MongoDB 2.6 with two shard clusters config.
I want to call a function dataStats() that I create and store in MongoDB. This is my PHP script:

```
$client = new Mongo();
$db = $client->mydata;

$db->system->js->save(array("_id"=>"dataStats", 
   "value"=>new MongoCode("function() { ... }")));

$db->execute("dataStats()");
```

This code gives me this error:

```
  'err' => 'Error: can\'t use sharded collection from db.eval',
  'code' => 16722
```

The reason is $db->execute method is using Mongo [db.eval command which is not supported with sharded collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Operations%20Unavailable%20in%20Sharded%20Environments). Is there a workaround for this issue? How can we call a stored procedure in sharded MongoDB from PHP?

Comment: I think you are trying to force what you are used to with other technologies into MongoDB -- and it doesnt fit.  There are no stored procedures in MongoDB and till its actually supported, I would not try anything "clever" -- these types of solutions just never work 100%.   My 5 cents.

Answer (score 1):

There's no workaround. `db.eval` doesn't work with sharded collections. You should avoid using it if at all possible, anyway.